# End to end BroadcastReceiver linking

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

There are lots of posts out there on using BroadcastReceiver for receiving messages in an Activity that are broadcast from a Service.  I've been through dozens and haven't found one that puts it all together.  Bottom line is I can't get my Activity to receive broadcasts.  Here's what I've done to date:

Service class broadcast:

```
Context context = this.getApplicationContext();
Intent intentB2 = new Intent(context, StationActivity.AudioReceiver.class);
intentB2.putExtra("Track", mSongTitle);
this.sendBroadcast(intentB2);
Log.i(TAG, "Broadcast2: " + mSongTitle);
```

Activity class declaration:

```
public String INCOMING_CALL_ACTION = "com.example.android.musicplayer.action.BROADCAST";
```

Activity class inline BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class AudioReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver    
{ 
  @Override 
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
    // Handle receiver 
    Log.i(TAG, "Inner BroadcastReceiver onReceive()");
    String mAction = intent.getAction(); 

    if(mAction.equals(INCOMING_CALL_ACTION)) { 
        Log.i(TAG, "Inner BroadcastReceiver onReceive() INCOMING_CALL_ACTION");
    } 
  }
};
```

Android manifest receiver declaration:

```
    <receiver android:name=".StationActivity.AudioReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.android.musicplayer.action.BROADCAST" />
        </intent-filter>            
    </receiver>
```

What am I missing?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In your service:

```
Intent intentB2 = new Intent("some_action_string_id");
intentB2.putExtra("Track", mSongTitle);
sendBroadcast(intentB2);
```

Then in your activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Woot! Broadcast received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("some_action_string_id"); // NOTE this is the same string as in the service
        registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
    }
}
```

This is the common approach to receive broadcast events in activities. Note that we are registering the receiver when the activity is in the foreground and unregistering it when the activity is no longer visible.

Comment: Thanks guys.  Both responses focused on ensuring the Service class properly set the action which was a miss on my part.  For some reason I thought the registerReceiver() piece would occur in the service but I guess not.  Works now.

Answer (score 0):

replace your service code with below code and add String  INCOMING_CALL_ACTION in your service or directly use it from activity class.

```
Context context = this.getApplicationContext();
Intent intentB2 = new Intent();
intentB2.setAction(INCOMING_CALL_ACTION);
intentB2.putExtra("Track", mSongTitle);
this.sendBroadcast(intentB2);
 Log.i(TAG, "Broadcast2: " + mSongTitle);
```